# WebSocket. Get connection to existing one

Tags: javascript, websocket

Im doing a script for a 3D chat which is using websockets. Every hour you get on the chat, then you have to click "OK" to get the hour in your profile. So i want to make a script that can detect when the box is there to click okay. I can see on the chrome developer tool, that i reviece a message from the websocket when there is a new hour.

I wanna do this in javascript so i load an javascript along with when i load the site. So how do i get already existing connection to websockets?

You can see on this image, that it provide a websocket
[image]

How can i get my javascript loaded along with the site to get that connection and not a new one?

Answer (score 6):

A webSocket connection is stored in a Javascript variable when it is created by the code that creates it. You need access to that variable in the script that creates the webSocket connection. There's no other way to get it.

You can examine the script that creates the webSocket connection and see where it is storing the webSocket object so see if you can to that variable.

Your Javascript can be added to the page via a bookmarklet or a via a browser extension or obviously by editing the original source of the web page (though I assume you can't do that in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to access a WebSocket created by an external library, so I didn't have the actual variable used to create it. Fortunately when WebSockets update, they trigger a `message` event on `window`, which you can easily hook into:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', messageEventListener, false);
```

Since there could be more than one WebSocket open, you need to compare the origin property (which will be the domain of the URI the socket connects to without the path). The data sent through the WebSocket will be in the `data` property of the event. Something like this:

```js
const messageEventListener = (e) => {
  if (e.origin === 'https://paygatewaway.example'
    && e.data.status 
    && e.data.status === 'paid'
  ) {
    // Handle change
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for all websockets.  Look at tradingview.com for example, it has a websocket for keeping track of the prices of assets, I can't seem to get its web socket.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan That's not a websocket. They simply send an XHR request about once per minute.

Comment: They are using a web socket, if you go to network settings and sort by WS setting, it's connecting to wss://prodata.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=chart/YP2d7EdZ/&date=2021_10_20-12_47 , for some reason I can't seem to get the responses from this websocket.  What you saw was a ping XHR request, I thought that was controlling the price also but it wasn't.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan You're right. I didn't see the WebSocket because I opened my dev tools after the page had loaded. My mistake. The XHR request URL I was referring to is https://hotlist.tradingview.com/hotlist/US/volume_gainers/, which looks like it is controlling the stock prices. I wasn't talking about the ping one. Also, the websocket you mention I see lots of messages, like about 3-4 per second, being sent over it.